# Barcode scanner interface for JSF app, Applet or JWS?

Tags: jsf, applet, barcode, java-web-start

i wanna ask you about your opinion: I work as independent software developer, and i have a project (i haven't started yet) about develop a web software that can use barcode scanners to read information of products to use in a POS. I usually work with Seam 2 Framework (Richfaces & Primefaces) and i wanna use this framework for this app, but sincerely in my life as java developer, i never developed an applet nor JWS application, so i wanna ask you:

- Do you think that is possible to develop an web application JSF Seam 2 that uses barcode scanners using applets, JWS or another technology?
- If that's possible, which is better for that situation, according to technical aspects like interaction with JSF or with JAVA model components of my application, is more recommended to use Applets or JWS for barcode scanner interaction?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most barcode scanner simply act as a kind of keyboard - when a barcode is scanned the OS driver simulates keypresses corresponding to the digits of the barcode. So any non-daft application can "work" with those scanner on a very fundamental level.

If your app can get away with barcode-data in every input-field you could still use JSF.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, but my question focuses on the part about the interaction between the barcode scanner and the web application using an applet or a JWS application.

Comment: So your question is, more abstracted: How can my Seam Web-App communicate with an applet or another Java application running on the client?

Comment: Yeah, that's my question, and also if you recommend to use applet, but i don't want to depend of a client application, i heard that with applet you can get that, but i also heard about java web start but i never have studied that, so i want recomendations to start to study and do it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is possible to scan barcodes and QR codes in JSF applications by using the PrimeFaces Extensions 10+ component `CodeScanner`, which uses JavaScript under the hood:

- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/codeScanner.jsf
- https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/blob/master/showcase/src/main/webapp/sections/codeScanner/example-basicUsage.xhtml
- https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/codescanner/codescanner-widget.js